# Part of Hangman game:I keep getting this error:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 How can this be fixed?

Tags: java

This is part of a Hangman game where the word to be guessed must be generated randomly from a text file. I keep getting this error and I don't know how to fix it. Some help would be appreciated!

This is the complete code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class P3A2_SHAKER_3885537 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Print welcome message.
        System.out.println("Welcome to the game of Hangman! The instructions on how to play are as follow:"
                + "\nIn each round of the game you will guess one letter, if it's correct you win the round,"
                + " \notherwise you will earn a strike and each strike will correspond to parts of a hangman."
                + "\nIf you guess all the letters correctly before accumulating "
                + "6 strikes, you win the game. \nHowever, if you accumulate 6 strikes, you lose the game.");
        System.out.println("________");

        // Create file for secret words and write data to the file.
        PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter("SecretWords.txt");
        outputFile.println("math\nchemistry\nphysics\nbiology\nscience\n");

        // Create Scanner object to read input.
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Create and initialize variables.
        String secretWord = "computer";
        int strikes = 0;
        boolean finished = false;
        boolean[] foundLetters;
        boolean correctGuess = false;
        boolean gotWord = true;
        boolean playAgain = false;

        // Play game.
        while (!finished) {
            foundLetters = new boolean[secretWord.length()];

            File read = new File("SecretWords.txt");
            Scanner in = new Scanner(read);

            ArrayList<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>();

            while (in.hasNextLine()) {
                wordList.add(in.nextLine());
            }

            String[] words = new String[wordList.size()];

            for (int i = 0; i < wordList.size() - 1 && wordList.size() > 0; i++) {
                words[i] = wordList.get(i);
            }

            Random r = new Random();
            int randvalue = r.nextInt(4);
            secretWord = words[randvalue];

            correctGuess = false;
            gotWord = true;

            if (playAgain == true) {
                for (int i = 0; i < secretWord.length(); i++)
                    foundLetters[i] = false;

            }
            playAgain = false;

            // Prompt player to enter guessed letter.
            System.out.println("\nGuess a letter:");
            char guess = keyboard.next().charAt(0);

            // Determine if guessed letter is in secret word.
            for (int i = 0; i < secretWord.length(); i++)
                if (foundLetters[i] == true) {
                    System.out.print(secretWord.charAt(i) + " ");
                } else if (secretWord.charAt(i) == guess) {
                    System.out.print(secretWord.charAt(i) + " ");
                    foundLetters[i] = true;
                    correctGuess = true;
                } else {
                    System.out.print("_ ");
                }

            if (correctGuess == false) {
                System.out.println("\nIncorrect!");
                strikes++;
            } else {
                System.out.println("\nGood guess!");
            }

            // Print out hangman.
            switch (strikes) {
            case 0:
                System.out.println("\n_______");
                System.out.println("|     |");
                System.out.println("|    ");
                System.out.println("|    ");
                System.out.println("|    ");
                break;
            case 1:
                System.out.println("\n_______");
                System.out.println("|     |");
                System.out.println("|     o");
                System.out.println("|    ");
                System.out.println("|    ");
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("\n_______");
                System.out.println("|     |");
                System.out.println("|     o");
                System.out.println("|     |");
                System.out.println("|    ");
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("\n_______");
                System.out.println("|     |");
                System.out.println("|     o");
                System.out.println("|    /|");
                System.out.println("|    ");
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("\n_______");
                System.out.println("|     |");
                System.out.println("|     o");
                System.out.println("|    /|\\");
                System.out.println("|    ");
                break;
            case 5:
                System.out.println("\n_______");
                System.out.println("|     |");
                System.out.println("|     o");
                System.out.println("|    /|\\");
                System.out.println("|    / ");
                break;
            case 6:
                System.out.println("\n_______");
                System.out.println("|     |");
                System.out.println("|     o");
                System.out.println("|    /|\\");
                System.out.println("|    / \\");
                break;
            }

            // End game if player has lost.
            if (strikes == 6) {
                System.out.println("Sorry, you lost.");
                System.out.println("The secret word was " + secretWord + ".");

                // Ask user if they want to play again.
                String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Do you want to play again? y/n");

                if (input == "n")
                    finished = true;
                else {
                    finished = false;
                    strikes = 0;
                    playAgain = true;
                }

            }

            // End game if player has won.
            for (int i = 0; i < secretWord.length(); i++) {
                if (foundLetters[i] == false)
                    gotWord = false;
            }

            if (gotWord == true) {
                System.out.println("Congrats, You won!");
                System.out.println("The secret word was " + secretWord + ".");

                // Ask user if they want to play again.
                String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Do you want to play again? y/n");

                if (input == "n")
                    finished = true;

                else {
                    finished = false;
                    strikes = 0;
                    playAgain = true;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Which line throws the exception? It looks like it's time to do some debugging -- by checking the state of variables as the program is running.

Comment: Not the answer to your question, but ...  you realise you could get rid of the `words` array and the `for` loop altogether, and just write `secretWord = wordList.get(randValue);`, right?

Comment: Could you paste the full error message (the "stack trace")? It should say which line the error is occurring in.

Comment: @Alex  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 at P3A2_SHAKER_3885537.main(P3A2_SHAKER_3885537.java:70)

Comment: Fran, which line is line 70?  Your error message implies that that's where the problem is, but it's too hard to count the lines in the code sample.

Comment: @DavidWallace right. here's line 70.   `secretWord = words[randvalue];`

Comment: Interesting.  That would suggest that there are less than four lines in the file.  Did you check that the file was getting written correctly?  Does it fix it if you close the `PrintWriter` before you start reading the file?  Please try adding `outputFile.close();` before the line `Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);` and see if it helps.  If it does, I'll write it up as an answer.

Comment: I did that and it helped! Thank you! the game starts now but Im just having a problem with the words being guessed, I get a new random word each round.

Comment: Ah  yes, looking at your code more closely, I see that.  It looks like you're going to need another loop in there.  What I would recommend is moving away from your computer, sitting down with pencil and paper, and working out which steps have to happen in each loop (choosing a word, asking the user for a letter, drawing the "gallows" diagram and so on).  Some kind of program structure diagram might be better than a flow chart for helping you plan this.

Comment: You're welcome, Fran.  Good luck with your ongoing learning.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like the error is in the below block:

```
 String[] words = new String[wordList.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < wordList.size()-1; i++)
    {
        words[i] = wordList.get(i);
    }
```

Verify that the wordList array gets filled.

```
for (int i = 0; i < wordList.size()-1 && wordList.size() > 0; i++)
```